# How can I use the word "education"?

Tags: grammar

How can I use the word "education" when I want to say some education has been done?
Carried out education for~
Conductetd education for~

Comment: Do you mean as a student or as a teacher?  The vocabulary is also different depending what level of education.

Comment: The verb is *educate*. So, *John **educated** Mary.* But it's not clear if that's exactly what your asking.